# mysql databases

Tags: mysql, database, default

could you guys please explain for me HOW these databases ARE CREATED :

- mysql
- phpmyadmin
- information_schema
- performance_schema

I know it's a novice question, I might GUESS the answer for some of them, for example "the reason  phpmyadmin database is created" IS because I installed phpmyadmin and this database was created alongside . That's not for sure, so I just need some clarification.

Thank you !

Comment: Not sure about the latter 2, but `phpmyadmin` **is not** a database. It is a tool (written in PHP), used to handle the administration of a MySQL DB.

Comment: @Doug Ramsey - phpmyadmin creates a database if configured to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the standard set of databases shown when you execute `SHOW DATABASES` on a clean MySQL install.

- mysql - this is created at install of the MySQL server, either by the package management system of your operating system or the script provided as part of the MySQL package
- information_schema - meta database, it does not exist on the disk
- performance_schema - meta database, but it does store some files on the disk

Any other databases are user/application created.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql is a database server. It serves access to databases. It runs on a machine as a service.

Phpmyadmin is a php based tool you install for managing mysql from a web page.

The last two are databases that can be created by an application, such as phpmyadmin, for storing schema information about the rest of the database or tables of a database.

Comment: Yes I know Phpmyadmin is a tool, but after installing it, and 'SHOW DATABASES;' , I saw phpmyadmin database. FYI, I use show databases command and those 4 databases appeared

Comment: Then I apologize for misunderstanding your question. The intro made it look like you were comparing different types of items.

Comment: To clarify, the information schema and performance schema are not created by an application, but created and maintained by the MySQL server itself. "mysql" is also the name of a schema inside the database.